# bad interpreter error while executing cron job using cpanel

Tags: python, cpanel

the cpanel was using `2.3 python` verion, but my script need the `2.6` at least so i installed `python 2.6.2` and added this `#!/usr/bin/python.2.6.2` line at top of my script to point to newly installed python. but i am getting following error when cron job runs.

```
/bin/sh: /home/somme_user/public_html/xml_feed/cron_job_wod.py: /usr/bin/python.2.6.2: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

is this is permissions error on folder? or cpanel is not recognising the interpreter?
if this is permission error then i have check my permission on folder and it is `777` means read, write and execute.

so where is problem?

Comment: Are you sure the executable name is `python.2.6.2`? I believe it's more usual to have it called `python2.whatever`.

Comment: @Mat Yes, that would produce the error message `python2.6.2: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installed python (*not* the .py file) is not marked executable.

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/python.2.6.2
```

should fix that.